# How to make cells image popup on click in datatable?

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I create a datatable, one column include images, I want to get a popup window to show larger image when click cell images.

Code as below:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

dat <- data.frame(
  country = c('USA', 'China'),
  flag = c('<img src="http://bpic.588ku.com//element_origin_min_pic/16/11/14/2f4de8bcf22409518c2fe2d74a49d9c7.jpg" height="52"></img>',
           '<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Flag_of_the_People%27s_Republic_of_China.svg/200px-Flag_of_the_People%27s_Republic_of_China.svg.png" height="52"></img>'
  )
)

ui<-fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput('mytable')
)

server<-function(input, output){
  output$mytable <- DT::renderDataTable({

    DT::datatable(dat, escape = FALSE)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Target result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could use `tableHTML` to achieve it using `make_css()` which creates a css file that can be used in a shiny webapp. You can check out [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tableHTML/vignettes/make_css.html) vignette for more details.

```
library(shiny)
library(tableHTML)

dat <- data.frame(
  country = c('USA', 'China'),
  flag = c('<img src="http://bpic.588ku.com//element_origin_min_pic/16/11/14/2f4de8bcf22409518c2fe2d74a49d9c7.jpg" height="52"></img>',
           '<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Flag_of_the_People%27s_Republic_of_China.svg/200px-Flag_of_the_People%27s_Republic_of_China.svg.png" height="52"></img>'
  )
)
```

Use `make_css()` to create `css` that allows you to expand an image. It would look like this:

```
img {
  transition: transform 0.25s ease;;
}
img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

ui<-fluidPage(
  br(),
  tags$style(make_css(list(c('img'),
                           c('transition'),
                           c('transform 0.25s ease;')))),
  tags$style(make_css(list(c('img:hover'),
                           c('transform'),
                           c('scale(10) translate(50%, 50%)')))),
  uiOutput("mytable")
)
```

In server, create the `tableHTML`:

```
server<-function(input, output){
  output$mytable <- renderUI({

    tableHTML(dat, 
              escape = FALSE, 
              rownames = FALSE) 
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

The result looks like this:

[image: default]

And when you hover over the image, it will expand like this:

[image: on_hover]

Note: you can change the appearance of the table by using the selecting a `theme` or by applying css to the table. See the [tableHTML vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tableHTML/vignettes/tableHTML.html) or the the [examples](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tableHTML/vignettes/examples.html).

Comment: I want to enlarge the image to show the viewer, in your sample, if I change scale to 10, layout will not friendly, cannot see the whole image. Do you have any idea to move large image to middle screen?

Comment: i have updated the answer and added `translate(50%, 50%)` to `transform`, that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example I've found online which can be adapted to your situation.

```
library("shiny")
library("datasets")
library("DT")
library("shinyBS")

ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput("mtcarsTable"),
  bsModal("mtCarsModal", "My Modal", "",textOutput('mytext'), size = "small")
))

on_click_js = "
Shiny.onInputChange('mydata', '%s');
$('#mtCarsModal').modal('show')
"

convert_to_link = function(x) {
  as.character(tags$a(href = "#", onclick = sprintf(on_click_js,x), x))
}

shinyApp(
  ui = ui,
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    mtcarsLinked <- reactive({   
      mtcars$mpg <- sapply(
        datasets::mtcars$mpg,convert_to_link)
      return(mtcars)
    })

    output$mtcarsTable <- DT::renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable(mtcarsLinked(), 
                           class = 'compact',
                           escape = FALSE, selection='none'
      )
    })
    output$mytext = renderText(sprintf('mpg value is %s',input$mydata))
  }
)
```

source: https://github.com/ebailey78/shinyBS/issues/26

If I should have posted just the link as a comment instead of an answer please tell me and I'll delete this an do so.

Comment: I have ever seen this sample, a little different with my case, my target column is image not character, I'm not familiar with JS, don't know how to convert it to hyperlink, do you have any idea?